# How does Nebula channel a large current through her body?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In The Guardians Of The Galaxy, Vol. 2, there is a scene in which

> Yondu directs energy through Nebula, which Nebula amplifies to destroy an entire fleet of ships that had been sent by the high priestess. Nebula then escapes down to Ego's planet.

How is Nebula able to accomplish this? And how does she survive?

Comment: Nebula has some kind of power source in her arm and they overload it to fire the lasers, but it apparently isnt fatal.

Comment: What @JackBNimble stated is how I believe the story went. Nebula was the power source they used when the ship's resources were drained.

Answer (score 5):

In the course of the movie we learn that:

> Nebula got one of her limbs replaced by cybernetic implants from Thanos every time she had lost in a fight against Gamora.

> Nebula: As a child, my father would have Gamora and me battle one another in training. Every time, my sister prevailed. My father would replace a piece of me with machinery, claiming he wanted me to be "her equal." But she won. Again, and again, and again, never once refraining.

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3896198/quotes?item=qt3399593)

> At least one of her arms is replaced by such an implant. The implant enables her to destroy the ships. She is able to survive that because her implants allow her to take a lot of pain. This is best shown in the scene where multiple of her limps seem broken and she just snaps them back with ease.

Comment: @CodeMed I am sorry but i do not have any documentation it is just a write up of my memories. And i could not find any documentation. I am not familiar with the comics so i do not know if it is documented there. And even if it is in the comics the movie could adapt it in a differnt way.

Comment: What I remember from watching the movie last night is that the problem wasn't so much amplifying power but that enough of the ship's computers had been damaged that they couldn't redirect the laser arrays. Presumably, Nebula's cybernetic parts, including the part of her brain that got replaced, were being used as backup processing. Since her body wasn't really built for it, she was hurt by it, like plugging a 120 volt item into a 240 volt socket.